# Split a string with two patterns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a string `id=12345&data=23456`
I want to print `12345 23456`
Currently I just know how to split one of them separately by awk

```
echo id=12345&data=23456 | awk -F"id=" '{print substr($2,1,5)}'
```

and it's similar for data.
How can I combine those awk command to get the desired result?

Comment: Why not simply `grep -Po '\d+'`?

Comment: `echo id=12345&data=23456` as written (no quotes) will background `echo id=12345`, then assign `23456` to the variable `data` in a no-op. So what actually gets to `awk` is _not_ the entire thing you seem to expect to echo, but actually nothing. For proof, try piping the expression to `wc -c` to count the characters wc sees. Quotes matter.

Comment: Oops! Note that grep -Po '\w+' and grep -Eo '\w+' will also work

Answer (score 1):

regex groups can be one solution but awk can't handle regex groups but, gawk can.

**Example**

```
echo "id=12345&data=23456" | gawk 'match($0, /^id=([^&]*)&data=(.*)$/, groups) {print groups[1] " " groups[2]}'
```

**Output**

```
12345 23456
```

Comment: FYI the term is `capture groups` (or `capturing groups`), not `regexp groups`.

Comment: Oh. I did not know that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for external processes. You can use the builtin `read` to extract the two numbers:

```
$ IFS="=&" read _ num1 _ num2 <<< "id=12345&data=23456"
$ printf "%s\n" "$num1" "$num2"
12345
23456
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
echo "id=12345&data=23456" | awk -F[\&=] '{ print $2,$4}'
```

With `grep` and `tr`:

```
echo "id=12345&data=23456" | grep -o '[0-9]\+' | tr  '\n' ' '
```

Note: This above command will add one more space at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a query string to me...I would suggest parsing it as such. For example, using PHP:

```
echo "id=12345&data=23456" | php -r 'parse_str(fgets(STDIN), $query); print_r($query);'
```

This gives the output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 12345
    [data] => 23456
)
```

So to get the output you were looking for, you could go for:

```
$ echo "id=12345&data=23456" | php -r 'parse_str(fgets(STDIN), $query); echo $query["id"] . " " . $query["data"];'
12345 23456
```

For a quick and dirty alternative, you could use sed:

```
$ echo "id=12345&data=23456" | sed -r 's/id=([^&]+)&data=([^&]+)/\1 \2/'
12345 23456
```

This captures the part following `id=` up to the `&` and the part following `&data=` up to the next `&` (if there is one). The disadvantage of this approach is that it breaks if the two parts of the query string are in the opposite order but it might be good enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Code

```
echo "id=12345&data=23456" | tr -s '&' '\n' | cut -d '=' -f 2 | tr -s '\n' ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you're going to do with the output, one of these may be all you need:

```
$ echo 'id=12345&data=23456' | tr -c -s '[0-9]' ' '
 12345 23456 $

$ echo 'id=12345&data=23456' | tr -s '[a-z=&]' ' '
 12345 23456
$
```